# adding feature grid using ClientSDK

Tags: boundless-suite, sdk

I am adding a Feature Grid in the Map page using this [tutorial](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/usermanual/tutorials/clientsdkintro/editor/featuregrid.html) and I am not sure where exactly I have to add,

```
autoLoadFeatures: true
```

The tutorial says that I need to edit the feature manager section of the app.js but despite making the changes, I am still getting an empty feature grid.

Here is my code of the app.js that I modified,

```
{
            ptype: "gxp_featuremanager",
            id: "states_manager",
            paging: false,
            /*layer: {
                source: "local",
                name: "usa:states"
            }*/
            autoSetLayer: true,
            autoLoadFeature: true
        }, {
            ptype: "gxp_featuregrid",
            featureManager: "states_manager",
            outputConfig: {
                loadMask: true
            },
            outputTarget: "south"
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the tutorial you need to add `autoLoadFeatures: true` to the `gxp_featuremanager` section of `app.js`.

Given that your posted code has the line `autoLoadFeature: true` i would be inclined to say you made a typo.

Try changing it to: `autoLoadFeatures: true`

As the tutorial says, make sure you restart the application then refresh the browser.  I'd recommend a `Ctrl+F5` hard refresh to make sure.

Comment: thanks, that is the dumbest question ever. Had a long day that is all I can say